# Number of monotonic ternary sequences of size $N$

Tags: combinatorics

I have ternary number. Its size is $N$.
Monotonic sequence means every digit  smaller or equal to the  next digits in the number.

$00122$ - legal monotonic sequence

$1022$ - illegal

What is the possible number of monotonic sequences?

Comment: There are fancier ways, see Stars and Bars.  But we can ask how many with no zero? $1$ zero? $2$ zeros? And so on up to $N$ zeros. Add up.

Comment: @bof:  I interpreted "His size is $N$." as meaning the length of the word is $N$.

Comment: What you are describing is really a monotonically increasing sequence.  The sequence $222110$ is monotonically decreasing.  Both monotonically increasing and monotonically decreasing sequences are monotonic.

Answer (score 1):

There are three sequences where all the numbers are same i.e. 000, 111, 222.

Now, consider the sequences with only two different numbers. You pick a change point out of $n-1$ places (${{n-1}\choose 1}$) and you can pick $(1,2)$, $(2,3)$ or $(1,3)$ variations so there are $3(n-1)$ sequences.

Now, we consider the sequences with only three different numbers. You pick two change points out of $n-1$ which gives ${{n-1}\choose 2}$ and there is only $(1,2,3)$ variation. In total this gives
\begin{equation}
3+3(n-1)+\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}=\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}
\end{equation}
Remark: My $n$ is your $N$.

Comment: OP states "His size is N.".

Answer (score 0):

A monotonically increasing ternary sequence is completely determined by the number of $0$'s, $1$'s, and $2$'s since the $0$'s must appear before the $1$'s and the $1$'s must appear before the $2$'s.

Let $x_k$ be the number of times the number $k$ appears in the monotonic ternary sequence of length $N$.  Then the number of monotonically increasing ternary sequences is the number of solutions of the equation
$$x_0 + x_1 + x_2 = N$$
in the non-negative integers.  A particular solution of the equation corresponds to the placement of two addition signs in a row of $N$ ones.  For instance, if $N = 10$, then
$$+ 1 1 1 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 1$$
corresponds to the solution $x_0 = 0$, $x_1 = 6$, and $x_2 = 4$, while 
$$1 1 1 + 1 1 + 1 1 1 1 1$$
corresponds to the solution $x_0 = 3$, $x_1 = 2$, and $x_3 = 5$.  Thus, the number of solutions of the equation $x_0 + x_1 + x_2 = N$ in the non-negative integers is 
$$\binom{N + 2}{2}$$
since we must choose which two of the $N + 2$ symbols (two addition signs and $N$ ones) will be addition signs.

**Alternate Solution:**  We have $N$ digits in the ternary sequence.  Since the $0$'s precede the $1$'s and the $1$'s precede the $2$'s, a particular monotonically increasing sequence corresponds to placing two dividers in a row of $N$ stars.  For instance, if $N = 10$, 
$$**|*****|***$$
corresponds to having two $0$'s, five $1$'s, and three $2$'s, while 
$$**********||$$
corresponds to having the sequence consisting of ten $0$'s.  Thus, the number of monotonically increasing ternary sequences of length $N$ is the number of ways we can insert two dividers in a row of $N$ stars, which is
$$\binom{N + 2}{2}$$
since we must choose which two of the $N + 2$ symbols ($N$ stars and two vertical bars) will be vertical bars.